# How to return the Visual Studio currently open soution directory

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, ide

I have a Visual Studio solution that comprises of several projects and are separated into different directories.

In my C# or VB.NET code, I want to determine the base directory (or the directory that the solution is in).

A dirty solution would be to call the directory `parent.parent.parent` until I find a file *.sln, but I also have several solutions in other directories that I don't want to be returned.

I am just wondering if there is a cleaner method, maybe part of `System.Diagnostics.Debugger` or similar?

I look forward to your reply, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the sln file does not need to be deployed on the target machine - why are you trying to find it at all?
If you still want to use the sln- try at [EnvDTE Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution_members(VS.80).aspx)

> EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");
>            
> string folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.ActiveDocument.FullName);

Comment: This may not work if there are two or more instances open.  You have to find the correct instance in the running objects table.  Code is out there for this.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have solutions in other directories, presumably those aren't directories within your original solution, are they? What situation do you envisage where the "recurse up until you find a .sln file" would fail (other than running from the wrong directory)?

One alternative would be to pass the solution directory as a command line argument.

What do you need this for, out of interest?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers.  All were very helpful.  I worked with the answer from Dror and with a little modification to the following line solved this problem, thanks.

```
string folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);
```

The reason I want to do this is whilst running the code in the IDE I determine the current Subversion revision of the project so that I can embed this into the running software version.

This is done automatically.  See the article I wrote at codeproject:
[link text](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/svn_visual_studio.aspx)

If you look at the code you will see I perform the following:
dirinfoSourceWorkingDir = dirInfo.Parent().Parent().Parent();

I need to determine the directory of the solution currently open in Visual Studio but want a cleaner way (and if I change the directory structure this would break the code).

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Is the code being run from within the solution, i.e. within the IDE debugger? If so you can pass the solution directory as `$(SolutionDir)` from the IDE to the command line.